# Subclassing and saving PFObject creates a column when I want it to be local

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have created a subclass of PFObject called Photo and I want that object to have properties that are both: retrieved from Parse.com and local properties that I decorate from the local phone/user only. A simple  example of my problem is as follows: Let's say a Photo has a name in the database, but I want the individual user to be able to add a nickname to the Photo which I will store on the phone. Everything works well. I get the Photo Object from the DB, it is a nice subclassed PFObject with a 'name', I set the nickname of the photo to whatever is stored locally, and we are all good. However, when I save the object, the system automatically creates a column for the local stuff in the Parse DB (i.e. nickname now appears as a column in Parse).

Here is my subclass.

```
@interface SLPhoto : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nickname;
@end
```

There is no table in my DB called nickname. However, when I save this object with a name and a nickname the column (nickname) is automatically added:

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:photos block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){...}];
```

I want individual user's nickname to be store locally, the photos are global to all users. The nickname column is not intended for that photo globally, btu I cannot make it stop getting created automatically. Is there a way to suppress this automation? Have I created a subclassed PFObject correctly to do this? Should I just refactor this and store nickname with a relation to the photo on the user in the DB (which I would like to avoid... but if I must)?